# "No such file" with ksh, but script runs with ksh -x?

Tags: shell, executable, shebang

I'm trying to execute a shell script on OpenBSD 5.7/amd64. Its a test script used to test a FOSS project. (OpenBSD is one of our targets because it provides an ancient compiler out of the box).

When I attempt to run the script:

```
$ ./cryptest.sh        
ksh: ./cryptest.sh: No such file or directory
```

However, if I add `-x` for debugging, the script can magically be found:

```
$ ksh -x ./cryptest.sh 
+ TEST_RESULTS=cryptest-result.txt
+ ADD_CXXFLAGS=
+ uname -s
+ grep -i -c darwin
+ IS_DARWIN=0
+ uname -s
+ grep -i -c linux
+ IS_LINUX=0
+ uname -s
+ grep -i -c cygwin
+ IS_CYGWIN=0
+ uname -s
+ grep -i -c mingw
+ IS_MINGW=0
+ [ -z  ]
+ [ 0 -ne 0 ]
+ [ 0 -ne 0 ]
+ [ 0 -ne 0 ]
+ [ 0 -ne 0 ]
+ -x c++ -dM -E -std=c++11 -
...
```

I unpacked the ZIP with `-aoq`. I've checked ownership, permissions etc. I ran it through `dos2unix` for good measure. I even provided `go+rx` to try and run it. All the things I know to check (which are few) appear to be OK.

Can anyone explain what's going on?

Comment: What's the first line of the file?

Comment: please show output of `head cryptest.sh | cat -vt`.  is the interpreter path in the #! line correct?

Comment: Were you able to make any progress with the comments here?

Answer (score 3):

Your shell tried and failed to execute the shell specified on the first (shebang) line of cryptest.sh. It is able to find ksh just fine, which is then able to execute your script.

Answer (score 2):

The path to `ksh` on the first line of the file doesn't match the path to `ksh` in your system.

Edit the file to reflect reality and the script will start as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It could come from your EOL encoding if you develop on Windows, you must write and save your script with Unix EOL.

Comment: The question states that the questioner has used `dos2unix`.